# why error when i have big input

Tags: c++, input

if n is for example 1.000.000 compiler stops working. Why? Long int dont help.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <fstream>
```

using namespace std;

int main()
 {
    ofstream fout`;`
    ifstream fin`;`

```
  fin.open("share.in");
    fout.open("share.out");

int n;
fin>>n;
    int array1[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fin >> array1[i];
    }


    int suma=0, sumb=0, sumc=0, a=1, b=1, c=n-2, a1=0, b1=0, c1=0, apotelesma=1000000000, mikroterhdiafora=1000000000;

        while(c>0)
        {
                while(a1<a)
                {
                suma+=array1[a1];
                a1++;
                }
                while(b1<b)
                {
                sumb+=array1[(a1+b1)];
                b1++;
                }
                while(c1<c)
                {
                sumc+=array1[(a1+b1+c1)];
                c1++;
                }



        if(max(abs(suma-sumb),max(abs(sumb-sumc),abs(sumc-suma)))<=mikroterhdiafora)
            {
                mikroterhdiafora=min(mikroterhdiafora, max(abs(suma-sumb),max(abs(sumb-sumc),abs(sumc-suma))));
                apotelesma=min(apotelesma, max(suma,max(sumb,sumc)));
            }



                suma=0;
                sumb=0;
                sumc=0;

                a1=0;
                b1=0;
                c1=0;

                c--;
                b++;


    if(c==0)
        {
            ++a;
            b=1;
            c=n-a-1;
        }
            }


    fout<<apotelesma;


    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what's the error message? What exactly happens?

Comment: 1) http://i.imgur.com/gO0itp0.png , 2) http://i.imgur.com/HOnyTre.png

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile; the dimensions of a C style array must be compile time constants.

Comment: @JamesKanze Some compilers (i.e. MinGW) won't throw an error when one creates traditional array of non-constant size, which is very misleading and simply bad, as the code accepted by MinGW won't run on other compilers.

Answer (score 1):

1,000,000 is a bit too much for a static array. You should create it dynamically:

```
int* array1 = new int[1000000];
// Do operations on array...
delete[] array1;
```

The cause of this behaviour is that when you create static array (`int array1[1000000]`), compiler puts it on the stack, which has limited capacity and when you exceed that limit, you have unfamous stack overflow, which leads to your problem. Dynamic memory on the other hand is stored on the heap and is limited only by your hardware, but unlike in the stack, you have to remember to free it, when it's not longer needed.

Comment: First, he has no static array, only a local one.  On most systems, there would be no problem if the array were static.  And of course, that is _not_ how one creates a dynamically sized array in C++; one uses `std::vector<int> array1( 1000000 );` (or `std::vector<int> array1( n );`).

Comment: @JamesKanze I meant local. One of my college professors always called local arrays "static arrays" (probably referring to where they are stored) and it kinda stays with me, but yes, they're definitely not the same thing, if we think about array created with keyword `static`. We can dwell on indubitable benefits of using `vector` instead of classic allocation with `new/delete`, although using `new` is not really an error, it's less safe, that's true, but it's all about one's programming practices.